# how to find elements and dimentions of theano csr_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, theano

- What is the difference between theano.sparse and scipy.sparse?
- How can I find the dimensions and elements of a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix()?

Comment: `x = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0,1],[3,0]])`; dimensions: `x.shape`, elements: `x.data`

Comment: I know. Doesn't work for theano.sparse.csr_matrix

Comment: They seem to be pretty much the same, with Theano being a subset of SciPy: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sparse/

Answer (score 0):

theano.sparse.csr_matrix is a symbolic variable. It don't contain any data. So if you access its .shape and .data, you also obtain a symbolic variable.

Symbolic variable are used to create a Theano graph that you can compile to a function. So this mean Theano is a compiler. As all compiler, it work in 2 steps:

1. Create a Theano graph and compile it
2. Use the compiled function.

There is a shortcut, you can do this to hide the compilation phase:

```
a_theano_symbolique_variable.eval().
```

If this need input to evalute the symbolic variable, you can pass it as parameters to eval() like this:

```
a_theano_symbolique_variable.eval(another_theano_var=the_value_of_the_theano_var)
```

Comment: The object type is SparceVariable. what I get is "AttributeError: 'SparseVariable' object has no attribute 'keys'"